# All TypeScript to Single js File - How to tell page which module to execute

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I just started using the feature that allows you to compile all TypeScript to a single .js file.  The problem I ran into, as you'd expect, is that the entire .js file is executed, and not just the module(s) that I need my page to execute.

Are there any built in utilities that allow me to specify this?  If not, what else can I use?  I work with a team using source control, so a solution like a NuGet package that can automatically get installed for my colleagues when they use the project is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I ran into, as you'd expect, is that the entire .js file is executed, and not just the module(s) that I need my page to execute.

You shouldn't have code randomly put at a `global` level. The global level of your code be just functions and class that are inert by them selves.

Then have the UI call these functions / classes based on current html. Some UI framework (like angular) can help you do this seperation in a neat way (example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Km0DpfX5ZxM&feature=youtu.be)